# How to monitor "check-in/push-es" to a central Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

If I set up a central Mercurial Repository where certain people are allowed to push to it, what convenient way can I monitor the changes going into that repository?

I'm used to using [SVN-Monitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/default.shtml) for Subversion.  It runs in the task-bar and lets me know whenever something new has been checked in to the repository.

Is there a similar solution for Mercurial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://saftsack.fs.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/hg-commit-monitor) tool looks like it might be what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

Use a RSS feed monitor and point it to the repo's atom/RSS feed (found in the web interface).

Something like this should do nicely: https://superuser.com/questions/9929/rss-notification-in-system-tray

Alternately you could set up a `changegroup` hook on the repo to be watched and have it trigger something on your system, but polling is probably okay for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are currently using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html) or looking for a Continuous Integration solution:

TeamCity has various apps/plugins like a VisualStudio plugin and Windows TrayIcon for build notifications. You set up a project in TeamCity to build when someone commits to the repository. When someone commits it triggers a build, which will send a notification to you. A bonus is that it tells you if the build succeeded or failed ==> {good code or bad code}

Answer (score 1):

Been giving [HgAssist](https://bitbucket.org/zerkms/hgassist/wiki/Home)  a try it works pretty well.